# How to use generic protocol in the method signature?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

The context is I have a class `A` that has many property but I only want to expose few of them and one of them is a generic type.

I then try to have a generic protocol (maybe that's an wrong name?) for the A.

It seems fine but when I try to use the protocol instead of the struct in the method, it won't compile.

Any suggestions?

```
protocol AProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    var t: T? { get }
}

struct A<Type>: AProtocol {
    typealias T = Type
    var t: Type?

    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
    var d: Int
    var e: Int
}

struct Main {
    func show<T: Decodable>(a: AProtocol<T>) { // error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'AProtocol'

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The snippet below is after I updated from @Sweeper's answer, there's a slight tweak for the implementation because originally in my project it is a closure.

```
protocol AProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    var t: T? { get }
}

struct A<Type>: AProtocol {
    typealias T = Type
    var t: Type?

    var a: Int?
    var b: Int?
    var c: Int?
    var d: Int?
    var e: Int?
}

struct Main {
    func show<T, U>(completion: (U) -> Void) where T: Decodable, U: AProtocol, U.T == T {
        let a = A<Int>()
        completion(a) //error: '(A<Int>) -> Void' is not convertible to '(U) -> Void'
    }
}
```

Could you explain why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a protocol with associated types like that. Protocols with associated types are not the same as generic protocols. The latter does not exist in Swift.

What you usually do in this situation is to introduce a new generic parameter, `U` to the method and constrain that to the protocol:

```
func show<T, U>(a: U) where T: Decodable, U : AProtocol, U.T == T {

}
```

The 3 constraints are:

- `T` must conform to `Decodable`
- `U` must conform to `AProtocol`
- `U.T` must be the same as `T`

Makes sense, right?

Comment: Yes... that! Thanks from me too.

Comment: The callee (method) does not get to decide what the generic types are. The caller does. `U` not only can be `A`. It can also be anything else that conforms to `AProtocol`. But your implementation only allows `A` to be `U`. Why not change the parameter type to `(A<Int>) -> Void`? @TonyLin

Comment: @Sweeper if I use A<Int> that violates with what I mentioned in the question in the first place, which is I want a protocol to hide the unnecessary portion of `A`.

Comment: @TonyLin I see. Maybe you need type erasure. You can read about it here: https://medium.com/@NilStack/swift-world-type-erasure-5b720bc0318a Or you can look it up yourself.